# Unable to load class 'com.intellij.util.Consumer'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.6 I got this error:

> ERROR: Unable to load class 'com.intellij.util.Consumer'. Possible
>   causes for this unexpected error include: Gradle's dependency cache
>   may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection
>   timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>   The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping
>   all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build processes
>   (requires restart) Your project may be using a third-party plugin
>   which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the
>   version of Gradle requested by the project. In the case of corrupt
>   Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing
>   all Java processes.

My `build.gradle` code:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Add maven in Gradle(Project:App name)

```
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

Then, use both class in gradle or, you can try it

```
implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```